# Get current page url on woocommerce taxonomy pages

Tags: php, woocommerce

I try to use `<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>` on a product Archive/Taxonomy page to get the current pages permalink/display the current pages permalink text, but it gets the permalink of the first product that shows up on the archive page instead of the current page's permalink. So instead of getting something like "/product-category/fashion/" it gets the first product that shows up on the list like /product/green-shirt,

How can I get the current product taxonomy page's permalink?

Answer (score 0):

Found it! I apologize for the trouble!

```
<?php
$obj_id = get_queried_object_id();
$current_url = get_term_link( $obj_id );
echo $current_url;
?>
```